# Partioning Mystery

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, integer-partitions, binary

Who has the wisdom to answer the following:

9 distinct marbles distrubted into 4 distinct bags with each bag receiving at least 1 marble,how many ways can this be done?

Thankyou for contributing!

Regards

Answer (score 2):

[James Stirling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Stirling_%28mathematician%29) has the wisdom.

> A [Stirling number of the second kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind) (or Stirling partition number) is the number of ways to partition a set of $n$ objects into $k$ non-empty subsets.

In this case, we multiply by $k!$ since we have labeled subsets.  So the number is $$4!\ S(9,4)=186480.$$